# How to integrate $\cos(x)e^{ix}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to integrate

$$\int \cos(t)e^{it}dt $$

I tried integrating by parts twice, but it doesn't work because an i shows up in the end and one gets  $0=….$

Comment: Have you used the fact that $e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ (assuming, of course that $t$ is real-valued)?

Comment: What are your limits of integration?

Comment: Write $cos(t)=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}2$, and it should be easy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making this an answer. Write $\cos(t)=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}2$ and it should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

One way would begin by changing $\cos t$ to $\dfrac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$.  When you multiply that by $e^{it}$ you get $\dfrac{e^{2it}+1}{2}$.

Let's try integrating by parts:
$$
\int (\cos t) e^{it} \; dt = \int u\;dv = uv - \int v\;du
$$
where $u=\cos t$ and $dv=e^{it}\;dt$, so $du=-\sin t\;dt$ and $v=e^{it}/i= -ie^{it}$.  Then 
$$
uv - \int v\;du = -i(\cos t) e^{it} - \int (\sin t) e^{it}\;dt = -i(\cos t) e^{it} - \int w\;dv
$$
**some details above may need work.  To be continued....**with $w= \sin t$ and $v$ as above.  This becomes
$$
-i(\cos t) e^{it} - \left( wv - \int v\; dw \right) = -i(\cos t) e^{it} -  \left( -(\sin t)e^{it} - \int -(\cos t)e^{it} \;dt \right)
$$
$$
=-i(\cos t) e^{it} + (\sin t)e^{it} - \int (\cos t)e^{it} \;dt.
$$

So we have 
$$
I = -i(\cos t) e^{it} + (\sin t)e^{it} - I.
$$
Solving that for $I$ can probably be left as an excercise.  (Remember that when you move $I$ to the other side, "${}+C$" will appear on the right side.)

Comment: Not sure your integration by parts works, because, using your first method, there should be a value $t/2$ in the result - the integral should not result in a periodic function.

Comment: OK, I'll look it over again.  I should probably write things like this on paper first.......